# How to calculate the duration of periods from long data with certain requirements

Tags: r

I have a big dataset where the employment status of people is recorded monthly for one year (>6.000.000 observations from >500.000 people). It looks like this:

```
ID <- c(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
Month <- c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
           "May", "May", "May", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", 
           "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec")
Activity <- c("Unemployed", "Unemployed", "Other", "Employed", "Employed", "Unemployed", "Employed", 
         "Employed", "Employed", "Unemployed", "Unemployed", "Unemployed", "Unemployed", "Unemployed", 
         "Unemployed", "Employed", "Employed", "Employed", "Other", "NA", "Unemployed", "Employed", "Unemployed", 
         "Employed", "Inactive", "Unemployed", "Employed", "Employed", "Employed", "Unemployed", 
         "Other", "Unemployed", "Employed", "Unemployed", "Other", "Other")
df <- data.frame(ID, Month, Activity)
df[order(ID),]

   ID Month   Activity
1   1   Jan Unemployed
4   1   Feb   Employed
7   1   Mar   Employed
10  1   Apr Unemployed
13  1   May Unemployed
16  1   Jun   Employed
19  1   Jul      Other
22  1   Aug   Employed
25  1   Sep   Inactive
28  1   Oct   Employed
31  1   Nov      Other
34  1   Dec Unemployed
2   2   Jan Unemployed
5   2   Feb   Employed
8   2   Mar   Employed
11  2   Apr Unemployed
14  2   May Unemployed
17  2   Jun   Employed
20  2   Jul         NA
23  2   Aug Unemployed
26  2   Sep Unemployed
29  2   Oct   Employed
32  2   Nov Unemployed
35  2   Dec      Other
3   3   Jan      Other
6   3   Feb Unemployed
9   3   Mar   Employed
12  3   Apr Unemployed
15  3   May Unemployed
18  3   Jun   Employed
21  3   Jul Unemployed
24  3   Aug   Employed
27  3   Sep   Employed
30  3   Oct Unemployed
33  3   Nov   Employed
36  3   Dec      Other
```

What I want to achieve is to create a new dataframe which has one row for every employment spell **BUT with the requirement that only employment spells are included where prior and after occured a period of unemployment.** This means I want to include only employment spells where people switched from unemployment into employment and back into unemployment and be able to calculate the duration of each of these employment spells. Also needed is the Starting and Ending Month of each employment spell. The final dataframe should look like this:

```
  ID Starting Ending Duration
1  1      Feb    Mar        2
3  2      Feb    Mar        2
5  2      Oct    Oct        1
6  3      Mar    Mar        1
7  3      Jun    Jun        1
8  3      Aug    Sep        2
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I corrected it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only those employment durations which are in between unemployed ones you can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, grp = data.table::rleid(Activity)) %>%
  summarise(Activity = first(Activity),
            Starting = first(Month), 
            Ending = last(Month), 
            Duration = n()) %>%
  #Keep only those 'Employed' rows that are surrounded by 'Unemployed' ones
  filter(Activity == 'Employed', 
         lag(Activity) == 'Unemployed', lead(Activity) == 'Unemployed') %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp, -Activity)

#     ID Starting Ending Duration
#  <int> <chr>    <chr>     <int>
#1     1 Feb      Mar           2
#2     2 Feb      Mar           2
#3     2 Oct      Oct           1
#4     3 Mar      Mar           1
#5     3 Jun      Jun           1
#6     3 Aug      Sep           2
```